# Including Javascript only if it has not yet been included in .NET MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

In a .NET MVC partial view, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<% ScriptCollection.RequireScript("path/to/script.js"); %>
```

That would require a method in the `ScriptCollection` object that looks like this:

```
public void RequireScript(string src)
{
    if (!_List.Contains(src))
        _List.Add(src);
}
```

Then, in my Master page, I would have something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <!-- Content would go here -->

    <% foreach (var script in ScriptCollection) { %>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= script %>"></script>
    <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is this:
How can I make the `ScriptCollection` object available to be updated by a partial view and also available to be used by a Master page?

Edit:
I do not want to add the required scripts in a controller, nor do I want to use a strongly typed Master page. Though suggestions on doing so are welcome if those methods are considered a best practice.

Edit #2:
This would be easy with extension properties. I could just give the `HtmlHelper` class the `ScriptCollection` property. Am I missing something like this that already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at Telerik's [ScriptRegisterBuilder](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-working-with-javascript-web-assets.html) class implementation which does exactly what you want. Or you can just use it as well. In addition it also has support for:

1. Combining multiple JS files into one which result in less requests by the browser.
2. Compressing JS files.
3. HTTP Caching.
4. Content Delivery Networks.
5. release/debug versions of your JS resources depending on your build mode.

Now even when you don't use any of the other stuff Telerik provides you can use the `ScriptRegisterBuilder` class but then it's advised to disable the automatic jquery & jquery validation script registration. See also the link provided.

Also take a look the `StyleSheetRegistrarBuilder` class. This is the nephew of the `ScriptRegisterBuilder` class and handles the CSS assets.

I did noticed the MVC2 tag in your question but my simple example uses razor and is just for making the point. It shouldn't be hard to make it work for MVC2/ASPX as well. Otherwise let me know.

**Master**

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>  
    @Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("~/Content/Site.css"))  
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).jQueryValidation(false)    
</body>
</html>
```

**Partial View**

```
 @using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("~/Content/Site2.css"));
   Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("~/Scripts/Test.js"));
  }

  <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
  <p>
     Bla bla bla
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the Telerik assemblies. They're a little overkill for what I need. Also, the open-source license (GPL v2) isn't the type I'm looking for.

I started a project licensed under the MIT open-source license and am hosting it on Google Code. It's a lightweight solution to my problem.

[code.google.com/p/script-keeper](http://code.google.com/p/script-keeper/)